# Stripe manage subscriptions server

Tags: node.js, database, stripe-payments, subscription

I would like to use Stripe to manage payment on my application.
I want to implement subscriptions system, and I already take a look at how Stripe works (with webhooks etc..)

Below you can see the differents subscriptions plan:

**FREE PLAN**
0 premium projects
10 projects

**STARTER PLAN (10$ / month)**
10 premium projects
20 projects

Imagine that a user pay for the starter plan. how should I manage subscription loop (timestamp state, and features state). I see 2 options:

- Stripe webhook
  Once a user subscribe to a plan, I wait webhook from Stripe to add him monthly features

---

- Server time management
  I store the subscription **start_at** and **end_at** timestamp in own DB, and I check every day that the subscription is renew or stopped.

I don't know if someone knows good articles or tutorial about subscription management.

Best regards

Comment: The initial request to create the subscription on a user is synchronous, so you'd know immediately whether the user's payment succeeded or failed, and you can use that to start the subscription. From then on i'd recommend using webhooks: continue to extend the subscription as long as you see `invoice.payment_succeeded` --- if  `invoice.payment_failed` `customer.subscription.deleted` you could to curtail access to features, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solution looks great. So I should only manage features models state I guess.